# Redis keys are getting deleted automatically in cluster mode

Tags: redis

I have a cluster enabled `Redis`. Every time I'm writing the keys into same slot. I'm using the format 
 `{ID}:key_name`.
I'm encountering the issue after restarting my PC. Sometimes the keys are getting deleted and this issue is not consistent.